# No element found FF - Error visible in firebug

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, http

I'm creating a global high score table. The JavaScript sends the username and score to the PHP through some AJAX functions and POST. The PHP script then takes the variable, and compares the score values to the file on the server. It then puts the new score where it should go on the score table, and rewrites the file.

I had it working last night, but now, when I call the function, it displays my code instead, and firebug gives the error, "No element found". I'm not sure what I did between then and now, but I just can't figure this one out.

This is my first time using PHP and AJAX, so I'm not sure where or what the error is.
Any help would be appreciated!

The exact error:

```
Timestamp: 4/13/2013 1:59:18 PM
Error: no element found
Source File: file:///C:/wamp/www/ajax.php
Line: 84, Column: 3
Source Code:
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an element with the `id` of "ResponseDiv"?

Comment: I know that someone is going to jump on me for suggesting the use of JS a framework when you didn't ask for one, but, if you are new to AJAX, you should consider using jQuery. It simplifies the AJAX and makes it much easier to send requests and process the responses. It may make your life easier, though your request, itself, seems fine.

Comment: Zachary, how dare you suggest such a thing.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel It's not a bad idea to suggest it as a comment, and include some explanation...which you did both of. Some people suggest jQuery for appending an element or setting the innerHTML, which is overkill. AJAX is usually a big part of an application, and proves to be more problematic without a library. It also introduces people to a new, cross-browser way of working with the DOM and doing other things, so it's not a bad idea to suggest

Comment: Ian: Yup! the ResponseDiv is in the html.

Comment: @Ian - haha nice to see you again. I am merely trying to help someone who is new to AJAX shorten their code to make it easier for debugging, even though (as I said, before), his request is well-formed.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel I would be open for the suggestion, but I have no idea how to use Jquery or AJAX combined with Jquery for that matter.. this is my first year of coding:P

Comment: Braden, good question. It looks like you're using WAMPserver. Is it running? What happens when you access your ajax.php page directly? What does "Line: 84, Column: 3" look like?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel And I hope you took my comment as positive and in agreement with you. I was just trying to say that most people suggest it for the wrong reasons, while AJAX is a big part and usually needs assisted by a library that knows the ins and outs of browsers. So I was agreeing with and defending you/your comment :)

Comment: @BradenEricson And what's the status of the AJAX request? You seem to be using Firebug, so you should be able to see some details about it. Such as the HTTP status code, the actual response returned, and things like that. Also, from another StackOverflow question I found, a possible solution is to add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to your PHP file. Not sure if that would actually help, but...

Comment: @IanHunter - No worries - I knew that - it's why I laughed :)

Comment: @IanHunter Line:84 of the php is just the closing tag ?>

Comment: @BradenEricson And sorry, I don't know how I didn't see the ResponseDiv element in the code you provided :(

Comment: @Ian I tried adding your header, no luck:/

Comment: @IanHunter running the php script alone just prints the code to the page...

Comment: As in your plain PHP code? If that's the case, your PHP isn't being parsed by your web server. Are you sure Apache is running?

Comment: @IanHunter yes my PHP code. I'm not sure if Apache is running, how would I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I cannot help you solve this issue, I will delete this answer, but I wanted to post it like this so you can better read my suggestions.

Start by changing your `HandleResponse` function to this:

```
function HandleResponse(response)
{
  console.log(response);
  document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
```

and post the result that appears above the error, in firebug.

What we are doing here is adding a way for us to see if any data was actually returned from the AJAX request. A call to `console.log` tells the browser to print the given argument to the console (in your case, firebug).

**UPDATE 1**

In your comments, you stated that nothing displayed when you logged the value of `response`. This means that you received nothing back from the server (in terms of data, at least).

My next suggestion is that you change the call to `MakeRequest` to the following:

```
<input type='button' id="test" onclick='MakeRequest("*");' value='Global Highscore Table'/>
```

Like before, leave the `console.log` line in the `HandleResponse` method, and post the result that appears above the error in firebug.

Here, we are setting your `MakeRequest` to make a request that passes a wild-card query parameter. At the time of this suggestion, I did not realize that the requested file expected two arguments, nor that passing a wild-card would error the script. However, this was still a good thing to do, as we found a new error, which tells us that the request is being received.

**UPDATE 2**

Now, cut and paste **everything** from your "ajax.php" file to your notepad or another, similar application. Then, set the following to be the **only** content of the "ajax.php" file:

```
<?php echo "Request received and response sent"; ?>
```

Again, post the result of the `console.log`.

Here, we are taking a step back from fixing the complex code, and we are going back to the basics. All we want to do, here, is verify that we can both send the request and receive a response.

If `"Request received and response sent"` is successfully returned as the response of the request, then we know that the error lies in ajax.php, and not in the request. If it is not, we know that there is a problem with the request (be it a server issue or the request, itself). If the latter is the case, there could still be a problem with ajax.php, but we must first fix the request.

**UPDATE 3 (final solution)**

Issue was found to be due to not correctly running on the local server.

Comment: That means that you are getting nothing back, at all. Give me a moment and I will post another thing to try.

Comment: Timestamp: 4/13/2013 2:40:09 PM

Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Source File: file:///C:/wamp/www/ajax.php

Line: 0

Comment: @Braden - Don't try my update 2! That error is a good thing! Please post the content of AJAX.php

Comment: what was seen on the page?

It printed half my code to the page, starting from the second condition in [ if( $hold[1] > $line_of_text[2] )  ] all the way to the end tag

Comment: @BradenEricson - sorry, I get it - the php code you posted IS ajax.php. Give me a few moments to review it.

Comment: [15:11:03.004] <?php echo "Request received and response sent"; ?>

and the error console gave the same element not found error:/

Comment: Wait, did you change the `content-type` of the request?

Comment: wait, when I typed in localhost in the url, the index page opened and the transfer worked!

Comment: Did it successfully print `Request received and response sent`?

Comment: I was running it from my machine, not the local server -__-

Comment: Fair enough - Good luck and let me know if you have anymore difficulties :)